# USB’s randomly aren’t being detected

Tags: drivers, usb, 22.04

Hi so I had been messing around with commands in the terminal pretty much all day and I wound up in a bit of a jam. So I decided since I don't have much to lose on here yet I'm going to start over using a bootable USB. I plugged in my USB (Sandisk 32GB), the same one that was working earlier, and it's just not showing up. I've tried everything I could find on here and the rest of the internet. I know the problem is not my USB because it works on my other OS, where I also formatted it to see if that would help..it didn't. I know it's not the USB ports because I tested them all in my other OS as well. And another weird thing is Ubuntu detects when my phone's plugged in just fine. But ALL of my USBs are suddenly undetectable. It's also not showing up in the Disks app. I'll paste some of the outputs I got from different commands I've seen people suggest on here so I don't waste any of y'all time. Oh and yes I've turned it off and back on again (:

`lsblk`

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0         7:0    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop1         7:1    0  55.6M  1 loop /snap/core18/2667
loop2         7:2    0    62M  1 loop /snap/core20/1587
loop3         7:3    0  63.2M  1 loop /snap/core20/1738
loop4         7:4    0  72.9M  1 loop /snap/core22/469
loop5         7:5    0  72.9M  1 loop /snap/core22/444
loop6         7:6    0 163.3M  1 loop /snap/firefox/1635
loop7         7:7    0 238.4M  1 loop /snap/firefox/2211
loop8         7:8    0  81.4M  1 loop /snap/discord/145
loop9         7:9    0 400.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/112
loop10        7:10   0 346.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/119
loop11        7:11   0  91.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop12        7:12   0  45.9M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/582
loop13        7:13   0 164.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
loop14        7:14   0  49.6M  1 loop /snap/snapd/17883
loop15        7:15   0   284K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/14
loop16        7:16   0   304K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/49
loop17        7:17   0 169.4M  1 loop /snap/spotify/60
nvme0n1     259:0    0 233.8G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   300M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 201.9G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0     8G  0 part [SWAP]
└─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0  23.6G  0 part /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
                                      /
nvme0n2     259:5    0     8K  0 disk
```

`sudo lsusb`

```
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05ac:12a8 Apple, Inc. iPhone 5/5C/5S/6/SE
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05ac:8600 Apple, Inc. iBridge
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`ls -l /dev/* | wc -l`

before

```
522
```

after

```
522
```

`df -h`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           782M  2.4M  780M   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p4   24G   20G  2.2G  91% /
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/nvme0n1p1  300M   60M  240M  21% /boot/efi
tmpfs           782M  4.7M  777M   1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs           782M  2.5M  780M   1% /run/user/1001
```

Yeah, so that's what I got so far. I'm so stuck, please help me lol